# SQL Server: how to set a column name as the value of a dynamic variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the example below (maybe not a good example):

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)
SET @var1 = (SELECT TOP(1) MiddleName FROM myTable)

SELECT Name, SSN AS @var1 
FROM myTable
```

What I am trying to do it set a value in a variable by using AS statement (in this case the first `MiddleName` value in the table `myTable` as the `SSN` column name). Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You should use dynamic SQL, it can't be done with pure SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what is it that you are trying to do - Is it assigning a value to `@Var1` inside a select statement that also returns a result set (Impossible) or return a result set where one of it's columns name is the value of `@Var1` (also impossible, at least impossible without using dynamic sql). Is there a third option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000); 

DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)
SET @var1 = (SELECT TOP(1) MiddleName FROM myTable)

SET @sqlText = N'SELECT Name, SSN AS ' + @var1 + ' FROM myTable'
Exec (@sqlText)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to do this, use `exec()` or `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50);
SET @var1 = (SELECT TOP(1) MiddleName FROM myTable);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 'SELECT Name, SSN AS [@var1] FROM myTable';
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@var1', @var1);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50)
  , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @var1 = ( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                        MiddleName
              FROM      myTable
            )

SET @sql = N'SELECT Name, SSN' + ' ' + @var1 + 'FROM myTable'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

NOTE:- Remember to have at least one space before @var1.